# Inside the CASE statement use subquery with generate sequence ID

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Inside the `CASE` statement I used **subquery** and in that **subquery** we want one column along with **auto sequence** value or **counter** value. Eg- 
Inside the `CASE` statement Query is like this, we pass one column as `col1` in `WHERE` condition & get the output as `col2` along with `CNT`.

```
(CASE WHEN (SELECT COL2, ROWNUM AS CNT FROM TAB1 WHERE COL1 = COL1) THEN ....)
```

whenever any value `col1` will be match then output of the `col2` will be generate along with the increment value of `CNT`.

`CNT` is here counter value like 1, 2, 3, 4, ..... Which one is the better option either use **counter** or **sequence**.

Comment: The query doesn't seem to make any sense? The CASE's WHEN clause must evaluate to `true` or `false`, not a table of data.

Comment: In Oracle, I would just use `rownum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Which one is the better option either use counter or sequence."

Do you always want the CNT to start with `1`? If so, you don't want a sequence.

There are a number of different ways of generating a value for CNT. The simplest is to use the `rownum` pseudo-column:

```
 SELECT COL1, rownum as CNT FROM TAB1 WHERE
```

This is a fine solution when you don't care whether a given row is `1`, `2` or `99999`. If you have some special requirement you might want to use an analytic function like `row_number()` instead:

```
 SELECT COL1, row_number() over (order by COL2) as CNT FROM TAB1 WHERE
```

Comment: please check the edited once. Here the pass one parameter & get 2nd column along with the counter.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your rephrased requirement. Please provide some sample input data and your expected output.

Comment: but i didn't get increment value when i use row_number() as well as rownum both. I want increment value like 1, 2, 3, 4, ....

Answer (score 1):

Generally, "better" depends on what you're attempting to do.

There's a few possible situations:

1. **You're returning a result set to some calling code/user.** Calling a sequence is likely an unnecessary overhead and doesn't allow for more complex row numbering expressions.

   In this case I'd use whichever is most appropriate of `rownum` and the various analytic row numbering functions, `row_number()`, `rank()` and `dense_rank()`

   Because of how your query is constructed it's likely that you should be using this method.
2. **You're inserting this data into a table.** I prefer the sequence being an identity column or, prior to 12c, being in a trigger. This is because code other than your single statement might do the insert and you want to ensure that all incoming data that changes the data in your table is treated the same way.

   In other words, don't use a sequence in your code to do this.
3. **You're generating a unique identity which you're going to display to a user and then insert into a table.** This sort of construct is mostly useful if you have a manual approval step. For the reasons detailed in (2) you *want* to use the sequence to ensure that data is treated the same.

   An alternative, though one that might cause locks, would be to do the insert and then display the uncommitted data to the user. The user then has to commit or rollback as appropriate.

   If you're doing either of these you'll lose uncommitted sequence values. This does not matter at all but it bothers some people for some reason.